# Is there a specific way to pass an array as a constant buffer to the shader?

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl

In c++, there is a value in an array, and when I pass it to the shader, the data is all 0. Is there a specific way to pass an array to the shader?

this is my code for set constant buffer

```
    vector<XMFLOAT4X4> finalTransforms = Animator->GetTransforms(_timeDelta);

    BoneTransformBuffer.SetData(GraphicDev->GetDeviceContext(), finalTransforms);
    auto Transform = BoneTransformBuffer.GetBuffer();
    GraphicDev->GetDeviceContext()->VSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &Transform);
```

this is my constant buffer in shader

```
cbuffer cbSkinned : register(b1)
{
    float4x4 BoneTransforms[96];
};
```

Comment: ``finalTransforms`` is not a pointer to your vector's data, so try ``BoneTransformBuffer.SetData(GraphicDev->GetDeviceContext(), finalTransforms.data());``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is missing a lot of information about your types and support code, but my first guess is you should use:

```
BoneTransformBuffer.SetData(GraphicDev->GetDeviceContext(), finalTransforms.data());
```

Also, this line `vector<XMFLOAT4X4> finalTransforms = Animator->GetTransforms(_timeDelta);`  is copying all the data an extra time unless `GetTransforms` is relying on return-optimization.

**SKINNING**

Note that for skinning you typically do NOT need a full 4x4 matrix for each bone. Skinned animations almost always use affine transformations (translation, scale, and rotation) so you are wasting 25% of the space in your constant buffer.

Instead, use:

```
struct SkinnedConstants
{
    XMVECTOR bones[96][3];
};
```

```
cbuffer cbSkinned : register(b1)
{
    float4x3 BoneTransforms[96];
};
```

Then you an use something like this to set the bone data:

```cpp
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
#if DIRECTX_MATH_VERSION >= 313
        XMStoreFloat3x4A(reinterpret_cast<XMFLOAT3X4A*>(&boneConstant[i]), value[i]);
#else
        // Xbox One XDK has an older version of DirectXMath
        XMMATRIX boneMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(value[i]);

        boneConstant[i][0] = boneMatrix.r[0];
        boneConstant[i][1] = boneMatrix.r[1];
        boneConstant[i][2] = boneMatrix.r[2];
#endif
    }
```

The HLSL code is then something like:

```
float3 Skin(inout VSInputNmTxWeights vin, float3 normal, uniform int boneCount)
{
    float4x3 skinning = 0;

    [unroll]
    for (int i = 0; i < boneCount; i++)
    {
        skinning += Bones[vin.Indices[i]] * vin.Weights[i];
    }

    vin.Position.xyz = mul(vin.Position, skinning);
    return mul(normal, (float3x3)skinning);
}
```

> See [XNA Game Studio Stock Effects](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Stock-Effects) and DirectX Tool Kit for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12).